# App stopping when trying to start a new activity after delay

Tags: android, timer, kotlin

I'm trying to start a new activity after some delay. But the app keeps crashing after the delay

```
Handler().postDelayed({
        val intent: Intent = Intent(applicationContext,loginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }, 1000)
```

please help. Thanks in advance!

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.aceri5.naada, PID: 15230
              android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.aceri5.naada/com.example.aceri5.naada.loginActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1940)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1618)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4514)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:68)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4472)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:751)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4833)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4801)
                  at com.example.aceri5.naada.firstActivity$onCreate$1.run(firstActivity.kt:40)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Application terminated.

Comment: But maybe you have to run it on UI thread.

Comment: Declare loginActivity in your manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *loginActivity* must be declared in the *AndroidManifest.xml* file. Basically the manifest file contains all the components that your app is using. Think about it as a "manifest" to the OS that is telling it the components used by your app, how it can interact with with your app, the permission your app is using and many more (more info [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro)).

To declare an Activity you must put an entry in the manifest similar to the following one (keep in mind that according to your requirements there can be more attributes you should declare):

```
<activity
   android:name=".loginActivity"            
   android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

P.S. classes by convention start with a capital letter :)

Answer (score 1):

try putting the below code in place of val intent: (remove val intent)
and do this:

Intent intent=new Intent(Yourcurrentclass.this,Desiredactivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

If not solved please share your exception which occurs in run section while running the app your stacktrace basically.

Comment: The code is written in Kotlin not in Java

Answer (score 1):

As per logcat message description, declare your `loginActivity` on manifest file.

```
have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```